# sqlx mapping to struct, how to solve "missing destination name"?

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I am trying to map a table which looks like this:

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time | timestamp without time zone |  |  |  |
| NL | double precision |  |  |  |

to a struct like this:

```
type Price struct {
    time time.Time `db:"time"`
    NL float64 `db:"NL"`
}
```

with this code:

```
data := []Price{}
err = db.Select(&data, "" +
    "SELECT \"time\",\"NL\" FROM <TABLENAME> where \"time\" > '2020-01-01' order by \"time\" desc")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

but I keep getting the error

> missing destination name time in *[]main.Price

after some searching the fixes I applied in order of what I found (with above code as end result):

- add the `db:name` to the struct
- changed above include double quotes
- checked case of column names that they matched

Those were all the common solutions here on SO and other places on the internet. I dont understand why this doesnt work, can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection tools in Go only expose struct fields with Capitalized (exported) names.

Try changing `time time.Time` to `Time time.Time`.

Comment: wow that was it, im a bit novice in go so didnt know this. Thanks!